# How to separate Ionic view into multiple views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I'm having trouble separating my app into multiple reusable componenents.
I have a page in which I want a list on the left of the screen and when an item of this list is selected, its details displayed on the right.

I have my

```
 .state('app.test', {
                url: "/test",
                views: {
                    'menuContent': {
                        templateUrl: "templates/main.html",
                        controller: "TestCtrl"
                    },
                    'testList@app.test': {
                        templateUrl: "partials/list.html",
                        controller: "TestListCtrl"
                    },
                    'testDetails@app.test': {
                        templateUrl: "partials/details.html",
                        controller: "TestDetailsCtrl"
                    }
                }
```

where test.html should load one.html only contains

```
<ion-nav-view name="testList"></ion-nav-view>
<ion-nav-view name="testDetails"></ion-nav-view>
```

Now in partials I have

```
<ion-content class="has-header">
    <div class="list card">
        Details
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

and the other contains my "detailed" view.

The problem is only the last `<ion-nav-view>` gets rendered.. What am i doing wrong ?
Maybe I started on a wrong design, so how can I separate thing so that I have :
a list on the left side of the screen and its details on the right side while keeping two "scrolls" separate ? (I don't want the details to be scrollable)

Comment: can you put together a codepen?

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** I think this might be what you're looking for:
http://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/10/02/ionic-master-detail.html

**Short answer**

Use `<ion-view></ion-view>` instead of `<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>`. Then you can control the scrolling inside your partials by setting the scroll attribute to false.

`<ion-content scroll='false'></ion-content>`

You might want to consider using `<ion-pane></ion-pane>` for partials. Simpler than `<ion-content>` as it fits to content. Easier to size but, lacks functionality like scroll etc...

It might looks like this:

```
<ion-nav-view>
    <ion-view name="firstPage">
        <ion-pane name="testList"></ion-pane>
        <ion-pane name="testDetails"></ion-pane>
    </ion-view>
</ion-nav-view>
```

Then you can use the UI router `$stateProvider` service to serve multiple templates using state params so you can have dynamic content inside of your two panes with the ability to navigate to other pages using `<ion-nav-view>`.

Check out the doc page for more info on routing and states: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/

---

**Why it didn't work**

The `<ion-nav-view>` directive is designed to be a container in which you can nest multiple views that are navigable within the app using states.

For example:

```
<ion-nav-view>
    <ion-view name="page-one"></ion-view>
    <ion-view name="page-two"></ion-view>
    <ion-view name="page-three"></ion-view>
</ion-nav-view>
```

Below is the documentation directly from the ion-nav-view page: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/

> The ionNavView directive is used to render templates in your application. Each template
>   is part of a state. States are usually mapped to a url, and are defined programatically
>   using angular-ui-router (see their docs,
>   and remember to replace ui-view with ion-nav-view in examples).

When your app runs, the AngularUI router module that the ion-nav-view directive is tied to looks at the 'state' your app is in via the URL and serves to the `<ion-nav-view>` directive the template that matches that 'state'. Using two  won't work because the UI router will only try to serve it to one.

> Ionic uses the AngularUI Router module so app interfaces can be organized
>   into various “states”. Like Angular’s core $route service, URLs can be used
>   to control the views. However, the AngularUI Router provides a more powerful
>   state manager in that states are bound to named, nested, and parallel views,
>   allowing more than one template to be rendered on the same page.
>   Additionally, each state is not required to be bound to a URL, and data can
>   be pushed to each state which allows much flexibility.